# How can I interact with smart contract

Tags: tokens, bsc

So I found scam smart contract which allows to approve only when you are owner.

```
 function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) internal {
    require(owner != address(0), "BEP20: approve from the zero address");
    require(spender != address(0), "BEP20: approve to the zero address");
    
    /*
    * 
    */
    
    if (owner == address(0x192939103120931280391284)) {
        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    } else {
        _allowances[owner][spender] = 0;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, 0);
    }
  }
```

When you are interacting with it via pancakeswap or other application, you will never be approved because of if/else statement. I suppose you can sell it without approving but I have no idea how. Any idea/help?

Comment: Without looking at the contract is hard to say, but most scammers know what they are doing and won't leave a backdoor. Either learn solidity and implement secure practices before buying tokens or just don't buy unknown tokens.

Comment: @Ismael Im almost certein that this kind of scam can be workaround. Here is contract https://bscscan.com/address/0xd000bf07970e4c336aeba4ab78a1e11e44c37f6e#code